# How to set id as value in select list?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `select list`:

```
<select ng-options="i.id as i.os_version for i in devices"
ng-model="selected_version_os_to" ng-change="selectVersion(i.id)">
</select>
```

And object `devices` looks like this:
[image]

As a result I get this select list element:

```
<option label="10.3" value="number:1">10.3</option>
```

How to set value options as: `id` from object?

Comment: `ng-options="i as i.id for i in devices"` and `ng-model="i.id"` and in `ng-change="wheteverMethod()"` and you will get `ng-model` value in controller whateverMethod()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use this

```
ng-options="i.id as i.os_version for i in devices track by i.id"
```

***Demo***

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.devices = [{
    "id": 10,
    "os_version": "10.3"
  }, {
    "id": 20,
    "os_version": "11.3"
  }];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select ng-options="i.id as i.os_version for i in devices track by i.id" ng-model="selected_version_os_to" ng-change="selectVersion(selected_version_os_to)">
</select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bu how to pass i.id in ng-change?

Comment: see updated answer. you can pass model value to `ng-change` function

Answer (score 2):

update html will look like below

**HTML view**

```
    <select ng-options="i.os_version as i.os_version for i in devices" ng-model="selected_version_os_to" ng-change="selectVersion(i.id)" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">
      <option label="windows" value="string:windows">windows</option>
      <option label="Mac" value="string:Mac">Mac</option>
      <option label="Lunix" value="string:Lunix">Lunix</option>
    </select>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm9q01nL/)

Comment: how to pass i.id in ng-change?

Comment: `$scope.selectVersion = function() {
console.log($scope.selected_version_os_to);
}`